# WindowsAzure.Storage SDK missing APIs in .NET Standard

Tags: azure, .net-4.0, azure-storage, .net-standard

I am converting a .NET Framework 4.7.1 class library to .NET Standard 2.0.

The library consumes a number of Nuget packages, all of which are available for both .NET Framework and .NET Standard and these packages include the `WindowsAzure.Storage` SDK.

The original .NET Framework class library compiles and runs correctly, but the .NET Standard library fails to compile, due to missing APIs (and some different method signatures) on the WindowsAzure.Storage SDK.

For example, `CloudBlockBlob` has a `DeleteIfExists` method in .NET Framework but not in .NET Standard.

The [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.deleteifexists?view=azure-dotnet) lists this method (and all the others that are broken in .NET Standard) but doesn't appear to mention any version differences between target frameworks. Did I miss something relevant here?

Is it normal that some .NET Standard Nuget packages have gaps in their APIs?

Is there a solution or a workaround for this (apart from re-writing the code that consumes these APIs)?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What version of Storage SDK you're using?

Comment: Afaik there are only task based methods, so DeleteIfExistsAsync.

Comment: @GauravMantri: I'm using v9.3.3 in both class libraries.

Comment: @PeterBons: Thank you! Yes, you're right that DeleteIfExistsAsync() exists in the .NET Standard version of WindowsAzure.Storage, so I guess, I need to re-work the code to properly consume these APIs in the async manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Peter Bons mentioned, In the nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage`, there are only task based methods, so DeleteIfExistsAsync for .net core / .net standard.

Please use the new nuget package for azure storage. For blob storage, you can install [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/10.0.3), version 9.4.0 or above, which does support sync / async methods.

The change log is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Blob/Changelog.txt#L47):

[image]

And here is a simple test with .net standard project with Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, version 9.4.0 or above installed. Both sync / async methods are there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ivan - that's a very complete and detailed answer.